# mongodb can't edit textare but input wel, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: node.js, textarea

I have a problem, i am using mongodb,ejs and i want to edit my movie from admin page, everything is ok, but wheen i change descritpion from input to textarea it don't work anymore can someone help me pls?
Thank you,
here is the code that i use

```
<input type="text" placeholder="newdescription" name="description" value="<%= movies_oefening.description %>" >


var inhoud = document.querySelector('input[name=description]').value;

fetch('/edit', {method: 'put',headers: {

                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({

                    'description': description
                })
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log('response received');
                console.log(res);
                location.reload();
            });
    });
```

app.js node code

```
app.put('/edit', function (req, res) {
db.collection('movies_oefening').findOneAndUpdate(
    { "title" : req.body.oldtitle },
    { $set: { "description": req.body.description}}
);


res.send('Got a PUT request at /edit');
console.log("change " + req.body.oldtitle + " to " + req.body.newtitle);
});
```

I get this error when i change input to textarea:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Comment: What error do you get if any? please be more descriptive for to better help you?

Comment: i get this error wheen i change input to textarea Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null